# How to use onchange function in select box at dhtmlx gantt

Tags: gantt-chart, dhtmlx

How to I use onchange function in select box at dhtmlx gantt. Please show in example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_lightbox_config.html) of the lightbox

> Each object in the sections array can have the following properties:
>
> **onchange**  (function) specifies the 'onChange' event handler function
>   for the section's control (for the select control only)

example:

```
gantt.config.lightbox.sections=[
    {name:"description", map_to:"text", type:"textarea", focus:true},
    {name:"time",        map_to:"auto", type:"duration", onchange:function(){alert('onchange fired!');}
];
```

Comment: Example: gantt.config.lightbox.sections = [
        {name: "description", height: 38, map_to: "text", type: "textarea", focus: true},
        {name: "priority", height: 22, map_to: "priority", type: "select", options: [
            {key:1, label: "High"},
            {key:2, label: "Normal"},
            {key:3, label: "Low"}
        ]},
        {name: "time", height: 72, type: "duration", map_to: "auto"}
    ];   Here priority is a combo box. How can I onchange function here

Comment: `onchange` works only for `Select control` so I think the example is wrong.